# Windows 10 UEFI Dual Boot Ubuntu (UEFI not supporting USB)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

I have 2 drives on my Laptop (Lenovo G500 i5 4GB Ram).
Drive C and and another drive of 269 GB (UNALLOCATED).. i.e. I deleted it so that I can install Ubuntu in it.

In my Drive C, I have Windows 10 installed 64 Bit.

I want to use Ubuntu and Windows 10 (Both)

My Windows was installed in UEFI mode, and I was making a mistake in installing Ubuntu in LEGACY SUPPORT MODE. My SECURE BOOT mode is DISABLED.

I have Ubuntu 15.04 downloaded, (Right now downloading 16.04+) and when I made my 16GB Pen drive Bootable to boot Ubuntu, in Legacy mode, then after partition disk and making swap, when i clicked INSTALL NOW, there was some error named "the partition table format in use ..." with 2 options "GO BACK" and "CONTINUE"

So i didnt install. Later I read it on askubuntu, that both the OS's should be installed in same MODE, i.e. If Windows 10 is installed in UEFI, then Ubuntu shud also be installed in UEFI. If Windows 10 is installed in Legacy support, then ubuntu shud be done in same.

Now I am trying to boot my pen drive in UEFI mode, but it aint booting, and windows 10 boots up. Like, my pen drive should boot and show options like TRY UBUNTU, OR, INSTALL etc. but it directly goes to the windows 10. (SECURE BOOT IS DISABLED)
When i was trying to boot in Legacy mode, it showed

Now my second ques is: Is 16.04/5 dont come up with such issues?

Third: I dnt want to reinstall Windows 10 in legacy mode (previous UEFI mode) so that i can install ubuntu.

I am very new to Linux so please explain it easily. Thank you :)

Comment: Chances are your USB disk doesn't support EFI-mode booting because it was improperly prepared. (Not all tools to create USB drives from `.iso` image files makes an EFI-bootable USB disk.) See [this section of my CSM page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html#creating-media) for information on what's worked for me and what hasn't. Note that this can interact with the firmware, though, so you may need to try two or three programs before one works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I can help you. First, you need to back up your files. This is always a good practice when partitioning. OK, the reason why you aren't able to download ubuntu yet is you only have unallocated space.

1. Go to ubuntu.com. You should see this menu on top. [image: Ubuntu_1]
2. Click on the downloads link. You should see this screenshot: [image: Ubuntu_2]
3. Click the Ubuntu Desktop link. Now you should see this:[image: Ubuntu_4][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3F7M.png) Fill out your options and then either select pay with paypal or Not now, take me to download.
4. After it is finished downloading, take a blank DVD and place in your computer. Set the menu up like this: [image: Ubuntu_5]
5. OK, now you can either drag and drop or copy and paste the download once it is finished to CD/DVD Creator. It should look like this: [image: Ubuntu_6]
6. Click on Write to disk. Now you should see this: 
   [image: Ubuntu_7]
7. Choose Burn Contents

OK, once you are done doing this and live dvd has finished burning, place it back in your computer and reboot. Then, after it is there you want to select Try Ubuntu without installing.

2.1 Go to the dash. It is the white circle on the very top. Type in Gparted. Click on Gparted. You should see this screenshot: [image: Gparted_1]
2.2 Click partition and scroll to new. Since you have unallocated space, it will let you do this.

2.3 What you need to do is format the unallocated space. Click on Partition again and scroll down to format. You will need to make two partitions. The first one is where your hard drive will go, and it is called ext4. The second  one is called linux swap and will be much smaller.

2.4 Finally, you need to apply all of the changes that you made. Click on apply, it is a check-mark that looks like this: [image: Gparted_3]

2.5 Wait for gparted to do it's thing, you will know when it is done.

3.1 Now, reboot the computer. Put the live dvd back in.

3.2 Go back to Try Ubuntu without installing, and set up your internet connection.

3.3. Click on the install link and follow the instructions.

Comment: Sir, one more ques, why cant i do this with a live usb?

Comment: It may be possible but I don't know how to do it. Since you are new I thought I would show you in depth instructions on what I do know. This should fix your problem.