# how to use gparted and make space for windows 7.

Tags: windows-7, gparted

I've made a mess i guess by not making partitions while installing ubuntu 16.04.
I've a 1TB harddisk installed in my laptop and in Gparted dev/sda is 923.10GiB covered by Ubuntu and it doesn't allow me to part. any solutions please? how can I part my hard disk space to install windows & as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Download gparted.iso (here http://gparted.org/download.php),

to make bootable usb drive i use https://unetbootin.github.io/

put it on USB Drive or CD, boot with your usb or cd.

I do your part with.

If you use gparted from your ubuntu you can't do it.
The HDD must be unmount.

Comment: I answered this question in detail, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/821559/windows-10-uefi-dual-boot-ubuntu-uefi-not-supporting-usb/821640#821640. This will work for Windows 7 too, same configuration.